# sipo not shift reg

Tags: integrated-circuit, shift-register

i need sipo IC that not shift output

not like 74hc164

this wear my output

the ic must have internal latch to refresh output at end of last clock

sorry for bad English

Comment: Why not use a 74HC595?

Comment: How is the chip to know which clock pulse is the last? The de-facto way to do this (SPI) is to have a separate signal for this, which can double as a chip-select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '595 has a built-in latch, but you'll still need a divider to count out the clock pulses.

Comment: yes but this will increase circuit, so carefree

Answer (score 2):

How about a [74HC595 - 8-bit serial-in, serial or parallel-out shift register with output latches; 3-state](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT595.pdf)